# I can't use buttons in java, I have tried even with the documentation methods and nothing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button

I´m trying to use buttons in a GUI in Java, i import all necessary classes and i the moment when i compile Java shows th next error:

```
Botones.java:4: error: Botones is not abstract and does not override 
    abstract method actionPerfomed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
public class Botones extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
```

I even tried to do it with the official Oracle Java documentation method ([from here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)) and it still didn't work

My code is here:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Botones extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

 JButton boton1;
 
 public Botones(){
  setLayout(null);
  boton1 = new JButton("Cerrar");
  boton1.setBounds(200,100,50,25);
  add(boton1);
  boton1.addActionListener(this);
 }
 
 public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent evento){
  if(evento.getSource() == boton1){
   System.exit(0);
  }

 }
 public static void main(String args[]){
  Botones window1 = new Botones();
  window1.setBounds(0,0,900,400);
  window1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  window1.setResizable(false);
  window1.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: You have a spelling mistake on the `actionPerformed(...)` method name. Your are missing an "r". Also, don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You should also NOT extend JFrame. Learn proper coding techniques from the examples found in the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)

Comment: Yes, I have corrected my program thanks to you. Sorry for my stupidity but I am a newbie and I really want to learn

Comment: I do typing mistakes all the time. You just need to understand what the message is telling you so you can spot the problem next time.

Comment: @camickr Did fixing the spelling mistake resolve the problem?

Comment: @DDmor A tip is to add `@Override` on the line above the method you try to override. The compiler will give you an error if the method you override doesn't exist.